# I am getting this error while opening my react-native app . Any suggestions?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

None of these files exist:

- screens\Components\Loader(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- screens\Components\Loader\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  15 | } from 'react-native';
  16 | import * as Realm from 'realm';

> 17 | import Loader from './Components/Loader';
> |                     ^
> 18 |
> 19 |
> 20 | const userSchema = {
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
> at Object.resolve (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:317:42)
> at resolve (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
> at E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:645:26
> at Array.reduce ()
> at resolveDependencies (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
> at E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:329:33
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (E:\gvosio-main\gvosavmobile\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:137:24)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm1X3.png)

Comment: Can you please share the directory structure of your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Components folder is located inside your screens folder, you would need to change `import Loader from './screens/Components/Loader'` to `import Loader from '../screens/Components/Loader`.

So two dots `../` instead of one `./` This will let you go one directory upwards first. Also, keep in mind that imports are case-sensitive, so I would double-check whether it's `Components or` components`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using `abc.js` instead of `abc.jsx`

use

```
import React from "react";
```

in the .js file, and the problem would be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You're giving wrong path for the Loader component.
Verify if you're using the right path and also check for case sensitive letters.

Finally do check for default export or regulator one.
Because if it's only 'export const' then u would have to use something like this {Loader}.

Hope it solves the issue.!

Comment: How do I verify if I am using the right path?